# US Tiger or OpenStreetMap route data: One Way Street and Intersection Data

Tags: openstreetmap, census, tiger, road, route

We're building a U.S. street routing application (finding paths for cars between two or more locations using public roads) and would like to use open source data [US Tiger Data](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/documentation.html) or [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) or other if available nationally.

We have worked extensively with the US Census Tiger Street Segment data before (we built a geocoder http://maplarge.com/geocoder using Tiger), and using the Tiger data is our preference. However, I'm missing two pieces of important data that I think should be there but I can't find them in the documentation:

**Question 1: Direction:** I know some streets segments are One-way, meaning that traffic is only allowed to flow in a particular direction, and I need to know if the Tiger or OSM have direction attribute data that can be linked to street segments. Specific links to documentation / data / examples would be awesome.

**Question 2: Connectivity.** When two roads cross it implies an intersection.  However, you can't always go from one road to another... for example, when a local road crosses a limited access highway, connectivity is often limited to certain "on ramps". I would like to know if the Census/OSM data can *reliably* provide information about connectivity at intersections. Specific links to documentation / data / examples would be awesome.

(This is a high volume application that requires our specific architecture, please don't dodge the question and suggest ArcGIS, MapPoint or a web service.)

Comment: MapQuest Open - have developed 'Open Directions' based on OSM data and there is an API available http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/

Comment: Thanks, that suggests the OSM data might be usable, but unfortunately they don't offer an explanation on their site and a web service api isn't going to work for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Data is not quite there for what you require - but some is...

The TIGER Edited Map maybe of interest to you.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TIGER_Edited_Map

[image]

Red areas are ways which have not been edited since the TIGER import.

Green areas are ways which have been edited.

There still is quite a large amount of fix up required for the TIGER data before it can be used.
http://open.mapquestapi.com/tigerviewer/index.html?zoom=9&lat=40.07546&lon=-76.329999&layers=B

Comment: That's a neat map.  I was just looking at it from your earlier link.   The enhanced OSM tiger data seems promising.  I'm just stuck on my two specific questions about 1 way streets and intersections.  You don't happen to know where the detailed OSM data docs on that are?  I can't find it in their wiki

Comment: OpenRouteService is a good starting point http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService - found this as well TIGER Routing USA - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TIGER_fixup/250_cities

Comment: Getting Warmer :-)  I found the "tags" they seem to be using.. but there still isn't much detail there http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#Used_OSM_Tags_for_Routing

Comment: I'm going to mark you as the answer since you lead me to the detailed tags.. I'm still not sure that these will work or be reliable but it is a nice starting point

Comment: Intersections: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/intersection

Comment: OneWay: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway

Answer (score 2):

oneway = 'yes' is how I understand flow direction limitations in OSM.

OSM shares nodes on intersecting ways. You can detect the ways by checking the reference ids of the nodes.

I have noticed that there are more than a few shared nodes at grade separated crossings which can cause some pretty serious routing issues.

Since much of OSM in the US was based upon a batch TIGER import, many intersections are based upon that data model. That is, if a motorway intersects any feature and doesn't share a node, then you can assume a grade separation. However, this is not *always* the case, unfortunately.

OSM has two related tags that indicate grade separation:
 - bridge = 'yes'
and
 - layer = x (some number)

The bridge part is self explanatory. The layer tag indicates the z value of the particular road at the crossing.

Comment: Thanks Peter!. Also on the oneway tag, I noticed things are also more complex.  Here are variants I have seen   case "yes":
case "true":
case "1":
case "-1":
case "no":
case "0":
case "false":